# Older Lightroom and newer Camera (e.g. Lightroom 4.4 and EOS 70D) - will it work?

Tags: canon, lightroom, raw, lightroom-4, canon-70d

Currently I'm using Lightroom 4.4 and I do not plan to upgrade at the moment. But I want to buy the new EOS 70D.

Today I read that Lightroom 5.2 will support the EOS 70D raw-format. So what did this mean for me? Can Lightroom 4.4 work with EOS 70D or do I need to upgrade to 5.2?

Comment: Lightroom 4.4.1 is actually the most recent version of LR4, it was released a few days before the EOS 70D, so no it does not include support for it. It is possible they could update LR4 to support it but unlikely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lightroom 4.4 will not support Canon EOS 70D raw files, no.  You would need the latest Lightroom 5.2 for that - as you say.

However you do have the option to use the latest version (8.2) of [Adobe's free DNG converter](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=5646), which does support the 70D files, and will convert them to DNG "Digital Negative" files - which retain all the information of the raw files, but which is a more standardised "open" format, which Lightroom 4.4 will be able to import.

It's a bit of a faff -- but it's free, and will save you having to buy LR 5.2 (though there are other reasons why the upgrade is worth it - but that's conversation for another thread! ;) )

Comment: faff? Can you define?

Comment: Thanks Mike for "Adobe's free DNG converter"-tipp. Under all conditions (quick workflow, new features) I consider to upgrade lightroom ... :-/.

Comment: @dpollitt: faff -> http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=faff

Comment: You just think that DNG retains all of the information of the RAW file, until you try to convert them back to .cr2 to open them with an application that can't read DNG. DNG strips all of the metadata that LR/ACR ignores, such as focus point selection in Canon files and CLS data in Nikon files. And you can't convert them back to .cr2 or .nef, so if Canon or Nikon comes up with a better processing application (i.e. Canon's Digital Lens Optimization that can mitigate the effects of diffraction) to leverage the proprietary parts of their RAW files your DNG files can't leverage that.

Comment: Although not required by the DNG standard, Adobe's DNG convertor also calculates black point and strips the data from the masked pixels so that it can't be recalculated later. The standard also allows for the 'correction' of defective/stuck pixels. But what if the identifying algorithm mistakes something like a star for a stuck pixel? It is gone forever.
See this discussion: http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/34540534

Answer (score 1):

You will need to upgrade. There are a number of bodges you can do, for example editing the .CR2 files so that they "pretend" to be (say) a 60D rather than a 70D, but then Lightroom will be applying the wrong optimizations and so you'll get lower quality results.

Comment: Thanks Philip for answer so quick :-). Editing CR2-File is interesting idea. I think lose optimizations an bringing a new step to my workflow isn´t the way I want to go. So I have to upgrade ... :-/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation.  Not ready to pay the "photoshop tax" after buying the 70D, I found that the perminant-licence LR I still had would not accept any updated modules, but:

- old (non-CC) Photoshop itself *would*, and then the ACR open-file controls can do basic exposure and WB.
- DNG to the rescue! Free converter, resulting DNG works fine.  The only limitation was that it didn't have settings for "camera faithful, camera landscape" etc but only "Adobe standard". I beleive those profiles could be found and added manually, but I did not pursue that.

Note that DNG converter is better than just changing the camera name in the CR2, if that actually worked.  The DNG stores sensor profile info in every file and the converter knew what to use for the 70D. The sensor chip is different than that of the 60D.

I question whether that works because the 70D has 14-bit samples and the 60D has 12-bit (right?).

Comment: Thanks jdlugosz for the additional informations. What did you mean with "perminant-licence"?

Comment: @micha "permanent license" means the last one I bought outright.  Now that I think about it, I seem to recall that LR 5 was also offered as one-time purchase.  But I meant I was resistant to upgrade at all because their new business model is subscription based.  In that sentence, read as: *The one I had, paid for in the traditional way, that still works forever without having to pay every month.*